# Where (or How) can I find Fourier expansion of antiholomorphic (antianalytic) version of modular J-invariant, i.e. Fourier[ J( ̅t ) ].

Tags: number-theory, fourier-analysis, fourier-series, modular-forms, modular-function

It is known that Fourier expansion of the modular J-invariant is J(q)= 1/q + 196884q + ...
It would be greatly appreciated if someone advise me where (or how) can I find the Fourier expansion of antiholomorphic (antianalytic) version of J-invariant, i.e. Fourier[ J(  ̅t ) ].
Thanks so much.

Comment: Since the Fourier expansion is a sum of powers of $\,q\,$ the antiholomorphic version is the same sum of powers of $\,1/\bar q$.

Comment: If $t$ is in the upper half-plane then $q(t)=e^{2i\pi t},q(\overline{t})=e^{-2i\pi \overline{t}}=1/\overline{q(t)}$ so it is just $J(1/\overline{q})$.